# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation- while creating the controller MVC Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, sharepoint

1. Hi,

   I m developing a provider host addin for Sharepoint online as
   follows. MVC5 Entity Framework with local SQL express code first
   approach. I m using visual studio 2017.
   When I try to add a controller then I m getting an error as follows
   There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Exception
   has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

   My Web config is as follows 
   [image]